# Mask the username of internal user in Customer Community

Tags: chatter, customer-community, chatter-groups

We are planning to implement custom community (with Chatter enabled). We are fairly new in the Community implementation.

We are in fact planning to migrate from a legacy system to a customer community. Our employees will have full Salesforce license and be logging into Salesforce and the customers will be using the community.

We are planning to enable the chatter in the community. We have a custom object in Salesforce (only Salesforce internal users will have permissions to create this record); however we are planning to use chatter on this custom object to use as the mode of communication between our internal users and customers to exchange messages using chatter post in Community on this custom object record.

Our internal users are primarily CSR agents who will be interacting with our customers. When an internal user makes a chatter feed on the custom object record, our customers should not see the individual name
who posted the feed, rather they should just see our Org name or generic name (XYZ inc.)

Is there a way to mask the username to be displayed as a Generic name on the community, so that the customers does not see the individual CSR's working on their records.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could turn on [community nicknames](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/networks_enable_nickname_display.htm) and then update the nicknames of your internal users to a generic value.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same requirements and was told it's currently not possible, but Salesforce was interested in the use case. I've created an idea, so please vote on it!

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000Tu5PQAS

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that you'll be able to do this easily. Its definitely not out of the box functionality. If you tried to limit visibility of your CSR agents in the community via OWD on User, their posts probably wouldn't be visible at all to your community users.

I think your "best" option is going to be to write a trigger on the chatter feed that masks, or renames the originator of the post as "Admin", "Community Admin", etc from the user names of all your internal users whenever they post to that feed. That's the only kind of solution that comes to mind. Check the chatter API or search for `[Chatter][trigger]` in the search box here for posts to find examples of chatter related triggers.

Comment: Hello, 

I tried the trigger option but there is no field in feeditem nor feedcomment that is editable to change the originator of the post.

Comment: update on my previous post.
As I coulnd't make the trigger work. I did enable community nickname on the experience and it serve my purpose.

Comment: @JulienSouchi The above is a 5-1/2 year old post and doesn't totally apply anymore. You'll want to look to the ConnectApi for anything related to this kind of functionality in Experience Cloud. Also, Internal User visibility can be restricted at both an object and field level from external users by setting the OWD's.